# fatal error: cpr/cpr.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
}
```

I wanted to run this on VScode on ubuntu.
i also added the CPR library location to the configuration as well.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/curl/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/cpr-master/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu18",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

but i am getting error like

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cpr/cpr.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <cpr/cpr.h>
```

Note : i am not good at adding c++ library so i asked this question. i also searched this over the internet but i am not able to get it.

The entire command line :

```
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test$ g++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: cpr/cpr.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <cpr/cpr.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test$ g++ -I main.cpp -o main
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test$
```

My file structure :

```
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test$ ls
cpr-master  curl  json-develop  main.cpp
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test$ cd cpr-master
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test/cpr-master$ ls
cmake  CMakeLists.txt  CONTRIBUTING.md  cpr  cpr-config.cmake  include  LICENSE  README.md  test
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test/cpr-master$ cd include/
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test/cpr-master/include$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  cpr
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test/cpr-master/include$ cd cpr
enigma@enigma:~/Desktop/test/cpr-master/include/cpr$ ls
api.h   body.h             cookies.h  cprtypes.h    digest.h  limit_rate.h  max_redirects.h  ntlm.h        payload.h  response.h  ssl_options.h   timeout.h      user_agent.h  verbose.h
auth.h  connect_timeout.h  cpr.h      curlholder.h  error.h   low_speed.h   multipart.h      parameters.h  proxies.h  session.h   status_codes.h  unix_socket.h  util.h
```

Comment: If you look in `${workspaceFolder}/cpr-master/include/`, what files and directories are there?

Comment: On another note, to build C++ programs you should be using the `g++` program, not the `gcc` program. So change the `compilerPath` to `/usr/bin/g++`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - If I'm not mistaken, gcc will go into c++ mode based on file extension.  But you are correct, better to be explicit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there is a folder named cpr and inside the there are many other .h files including "cpr.h" as well

Comment: Does VSCode, when you build, show you the actual command line parameters getting passed go `g++` ?

Comment: @selbie i am using this command to build
```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: That's the problem, you aren't passing the `-I` option to g++ to tell it where to find the include folders.  It sounds like you are editing in VSCode, but compiling manually from the command line.  Type `g++ -I . main.cpp -o main`

Comment: @selbie You *can* use `gcc` to build C++ source files, but the paths for the standard library header files might not be set, and the C++ standard library itself won't be linked.

Comment: @selbie ya now m getting some other error
g++: fatal error: no input files

Comment: You really need to paste your entire command line and entire  compiler output into your question.

Comment: @selbie Added the same to question

Comment: You missed the **dot**.  Instead of this: `g++ -I main.cpp -o main`  This.  `g++ -I. main.cpp -o main`

Comment: `-I.` instead of `-I`

Comment: still its showing no such  file or directory.
but i tried using other one and it compiled 
```g++ -I ./cpr-master/include/ -I ./curl/include/  main.cpp -o main```